# how to store the object into array and then displays all the objects in the create button elements?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

This is my code so far:

```
var cars=["BMW","MERCEDEZ"]; 
var arr = [];
for (var j=0; j<= 1; j++){
    for (var x=0; x <= 5; x++) {
        arr ={
            index: a,
            name: arr[j] + (x+(5*j)),
            price: (x+(5*j))
        };
    }
}
```

I want to display all the objects from `arr[]` in the create button elements:

```
btnShow = document.createElement("input");
btnShow.setAttribute("type", "button");
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Your arr[] does not have objects, because its object itself. you need to do `arr.push({...})`

Comment: where do I have to arr.push({...}) ? 
Can you give an example?

Comment: what is a in index key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add elements to the array not set different object instad of the array

replace

```
arr = { 
          index: a, 
          name: cars[x+(5*j)],
          price: cars[x+(5*j)]
      };
```

with

```
arr.push({ 
          index: a, 
          name: cars[x+(5*j)],
          price: cars[x+(5*j)]
      });
```

Comment: How do I display all the contents of the object into buttons to create elements?